# What does the interval $]-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}[$ mean?

Tags: notation

It could be a misprint or typo in what I'm reading, but I just want to make sure.

I'm reading Loring Tu's "An Introduction to Manifolds", and at the end of the first chapter, one of the problem states:

$\textbf{1.3 A diffeomorphism of an open interval with}\,\,\mathbb{R}$

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $V\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. A $C^\infty$ map $F: U\rightarrow V$ is called a *diffeomorphism* if it is bijective and has a $C^\infty$ inverse $F^{-1}:V\rightarrow U$.

(a) Show that the function $f: \,\,\,]-\pi/2, \pi/2[\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x)=\tan(x)$ is a diffeomorphism.

To be clear, I'm not asking for help with the problem, just the notation he uses. Elsewhere in the text, it appears that every time he mentions an open interval, he uses this $]a,b[$ notation, but for closed intervals he uses the traditional $[a,b]$.

Is this notation commonly used, or likely some sort of misprint with the pdf I'm reading from?

Comment: At some places in the world it is *the* standard notation for open intervals.

Comment: Could you point me to more info about it? This sort of thing seemed difficult to search for when I tried

Comment: There is really nothing more to it that and inverted bracket is used instead of a parenthesis. I am pretty sure the question is a duplicate which is why I did not answer it.

Comment: You're welcome to close it or delete it, then!